# copying from MS Word to editable div and saving to DB results in some missing spaces between words

Tags: database, html

I have an editable div. I save it's content to database. The problem is when i copy text from the MS Word to the editable div, all formatting is ok. But when I retrieve from database what i saved, there are some words with no spaces between them.
The text I copy is in russian.

I have and editable div

```
<div class='myh5'>Контент страницы</div>
<div ID='contentDiv' contenteditable='true'> 
    Выберите страничку...
</div>
```

and a hidden input field where i copy content of the editable div to save it to the database:

```
<form action = '".site_url('admin/save')."' method='post'>
<input type='text' name='content' id='input' class='displayNone'></input>
<input type='submit' value='Сохранить изменения' onclick='getPageContent()'></input>
```

here's how i copy the content to the input field with javascript:

```
// send the data from the editable div
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var contentDiv = document.getElementById('contentDiv');
function getPageContent() {
    input.value = $('#contentDiv').html();
}
```

and here is how i save the content to database using php framework called CodeIgniter.

```
$content = $this->input->post('content');
    $content = addslashes($content);    
    $sql = "
        UPDATE pages
        SET content_$lang='$content', name='$renamePage', title_$lang='$title'
        WHERE name='$pageName'
    ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

So what can be the reason? What can I do to have my text in database as it was in editable div?

Comment: Check the formatting before you save but after you paste. Are the spaces missing from there as well? If so, then the problem might be how you read the data from the DOM. Use a debugger and check your `$content` variable or just do a simple `echo $content` to check.